# Why can't see pod resources in the cluster which created by microk8s?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

Installed `microk8s` by

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.17/stable
```

Alias

```
alias kubectl='microk8s.kubectl'
```

Current docker container:

```
docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
b07100cc21cc        first-app:v1        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   good_sala
```

File structure:

```
  kubernetes/         # Kubernetes manifests to deploy the application
    deployment.yaml
    service.yaml
```

In deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: first-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: first-app
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: first-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: first-app
        image: first-app:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

In service.yaml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: first-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: first-app
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

Deploy:

```
kubectl -n default create -f kubernetes
deployment.apps/first-app created
service/first-app created
```

Check pod:

```
kubectl -n default get pod
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Check service:

```
kubectl -n default get service | grep first-app
first-app     NodePort    10.152.183.215   <none>        80:30366/TCP   7m52s
```

Why can't find any pods?

If I deploy the same thing to minikube, it works.

Comment: probably can't bind to port 80?

Comment: @muru Yes, 80 is using by OpenStack’s dashboard created by microstack. Is it the reason?